# Ref Request: Geometric Du-Bois Raymond Lemma

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry

I've been looking everywhere for a reference for this "geometric" Du Bois-Raymond Lemma:

[image]

Here $\frac{DY}{dt}$ denotes the covariant derivative along $y$.

Comment: It would help a lot if you were giving the reference of the paper (or book?) you cite.

Comment: By the way, isn't "du Bois-Reymond" the right spelling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the second reference you gave in your comment, see [3].
In this paper, the authors refer to

> the following “Du Bois-Raymond lemma”, a straightforward extension of the classical lemma to a Riemannian manifold

Apart from the misspell, it seems that du Bois-Reymond's classical lemma has its own [wikipedia article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemme_fondamental_du_calcul_des_variations#Lemme_de_Du_Bois-Reymond), which includes bibliographic references. Note that this wikipedia entry is in French, and the English version does not seem to have as much information. Du Bois-Reymond's original papers were published in [1, 2].

[1] P. du Bois-Reymond, Erläuterungen zu den Anfangsgründen der Variationsrechnung », *Mathematische Annalen* **15**, no 2,‎ 1879, p. 283-314

[2] P. du Bois-Reymond, Fortsetzung der Erläuterungen zu den Anfangsgründen der Variationsrechnung, *Mathematische Annalen* **15**, no 2,‎ 1879, p. 564-576

[3] J. Langer, and D.A. Singer, Curve straightening and a minimax argument for closed elastic curves, *Topology* **24** (1985), no. 1, 75--88.